# C++ raw pointer and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, shared

I am working with `std::shared_ptr` and during my software development I met a couple
of cases that let me doubt about memory management. I had a third party library that
gave me always raw pointers from functions and in my code I was transforming them
into `std::shared_ptr` (from std and not from boost. By the way what is the difference between
the two?). So let's say I have the following code:

```
ClassA* raw = new ClassA;
std::shared_ptr<ClassA> shared(raw);
```

What happens now when the shared pointer goes out of scope (let's say it was declared locally in a function
and now I am exiting the function). Will the `ClassA` object still exist because a raw pointer
is pointing to it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No it won't. By giving the raw pointer to the `shared_ptr`, you are giving `shared_ptr` the responsibility of deleting it. It will do this when the last `shared_ptr` object referencing your `ClassA` instance no longer exists. Raw pointers don't count.

Comment: Just to give a reason why: shared_ptr does not consider the raw pointer because there is no way shared_ptr could know about it. If you think about how you would implement a shared_ptr yourself then you will see that you can't detect if there are any raw pointers to the data.

Comment: +1. Also, this is why you should `new` the object on the same line as you create the `shared_ptr`.  Even better, use [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Comment: Thanks, in fact I agree that there is no way in finding out if a raw pointer is pointing to the object. In this case it is just dangerous for the raw pointer because it will point to a destroyed object because the shared_ptr will destroy it when out of scope

Comment: what if he passes the raw ptr to a second shared_ptr, will the first shared_ptr still counter incease?

Answer (score 5):

no.  The shared pointer will delete it.

If you have a third party library providing you with a pointer, you need to be sure that you delete it in the correct way.  If the 3rd party lib allocated it with 'malloc' for example, then you need to use the implementation of 'free' that the lib uses.  You need to be sure how it was allocated.

Does the library offer a way to destroy objects it provides you with?  In which case you should use that function to destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

No, `ClassA` object will be destroyed. Unless you didn't copied `shared_ptr` somewhere out of scope so its reference counter is > 1.