# C++11 storing multiple shared pointers as raw pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

My question concerns `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` in C++11. I have two vectors, the first one stores smart pointers and the second one stores raw pointers. The first vector works as I had expepted but vector2 is just confusing...

### Code sample

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> vector1;
    vector1.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(1));
    vector1.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(2));
    vector1.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(3));

    std::vector<int*> vector2;
    vector2.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(4).get());
    vector2.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(5).get());
    vector2.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(6).get());

    std::cout << "vector1 values:" << std::endl;
    for(auto &value: vector1) { std::cout << *value << std::endl; }

    std::cout << "vector2 values:" << std::endl;
    for(auto &value: vector2) { std::cout << *value << std::endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
vector1 values:
1
2
3
vector2 values:
6
6
6
```

### Question

I realize that it would be much simpler to create raw pointers to begin with and not try to convert smart pointers but it made me curious to know **why** this is happening? Also why does each push change all of the values in vector2?

### Links

Here are some questions that I found in stackoverflow but they didn't answer my question or maybe I didn't understand the answers...

- [shared_ptr for a raw pointer argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405124/shared-ptr-for-a-raw-pointer-argument)
- [Are there any downsides with using make_shared to create a shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147600/are-there-any-downsides-with-using-make-shared-to-create-a-shared-ptr)
- [C++ raw pointer and std::shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425073/c-raw-pointer-and-stdshared-ptr)
- [Extracting a raw pointer from a shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962991/extracting-a-raw-pointer-from-a-shared-ptr)

Comment: Great first question! Very well formatted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you'll use a `shared_ptr` is that you want the memory it points to to be freed when all instances that point to it go out of scope. The `shared_ptr` is destroyed right after you call `.get()` on it, so you immediately have a dangling pointer. The result of the dereference operation is undefined, which means that it may or may not return a value that makes sense, or it could even do something completely unrelated (like crashing).

This is a feature. You *want* this to happen: otherwise, you'd be leaking memory. Imagine this code:

```
vector<int> integers;
integers.push_back(*make_shared<int>(6).get());
```

If the memory wasn't freed, there would be *no way* to release it afterwards, because there's no way you could recover the shared_ptr's managed pointer.

Comment: This makes a little bit more sense now, but wouldn't it make more sense if `std::shared_ptr::get` returned an entirely new pointer instead of a pointer to the managed object?

Comment: @Oak, this would force any type that you use with a `shared_ptr` to be copiable, and it would very possibly not work with polymorphism because of C++'s copy mechanism. It would also be very slow on large data structures, and it would also burden the developer with freeing the pointer (which goes against the point of using a `shared_ptr` in the first place). You also couldn't use it with array types because it's impossible to get the length of an array created with `new` (and therefore the `shared_ptr` wouldn't know how much data to copy when returning a new pointer).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for an elaborate and easily understandable answer :)

Comment: @Oak No, because the `get()` method is used to extract the pointer out of the smart pointer, not to get a completely new pointer.   You're probably getting a '6' as the output since each of your three allocations are probably getting the same piece of memory, thus you're only getting the last value.  However (as mentioned elsewhere) this is undefined behaviour as you are dereferencing a pointer which has already been deleted.

Answer (score 10):

You are seeing *undefined behaviour*. When you do this:

```
vector2.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(4).get());
```

You are creating a temporary `shared_ptr`, and copying a pointer to its managed object into your `vector`. This immediately becomes a dangling pointer.